# Allowing users to select which flow to roll back to django-viewflow

Tags: django, django-views, workflow, django-viewflow

Hey all  i have been using viewflow as the workflow engine in my django project. I wanted to know if it was possible to allow users to 'select' which flow they wish to roll back to if lets say an approval was rejected.

[image]

Here , the director chooses 'Reject' , however it doesn't make sense to end the flow here , instead it should be a be a selectable 'roll back' , so that the the people down the line do not need to restart the entire process again.

Here's what i have done so far  :

## flows.py

```
#director will approve or dont approve
approve_by_director = flow.View(
    UpdateProcessView,
    form_class=DirectorApproveForm,
    task_title="Approval By Director"
).Permission("cash.director"
).Next(this.check_director)

check_director = flow.If(
    cond=lambda act: act.process.director,
    task_title="Processing"
).Then(this.send).Else(this.justification)

#justifications for the roll back.
justification = flow.View(
    JustificationView,
    task_title="Justifications for Roll Back"
).Assign(lambda act: self.request.user
).Permission(auto_create=True
).Next(this.roll_back)

roll_back = flow.Handler(this.roll_back_call).Next(this.approve_by_preparer)  ##<---- here , i am just sending it back to the 'preparer' , however it would be great if this could be dynamic!

end = flow.End()

def roll_back_call(self, activation):
    esig = ESignatures.objects.filter(paymentVoucherProcess = activation.process).filter(voided = False)
    docu = Attachment.objects.filter(paymentVoucherProcess = activation.process).filter(voided = False)
    if len(esig) > 0 :
        for sig in esig:
            sig.voided = True
            sig.save()
    if len(docu) > 0 :
        for doc in docu:
            doc.voided = True
            doc.save()
    activation.process.preparer = False
    activation.process.verifier = False
    activation.process.treasury = False
    activation.process.director = False
```

The problem here is that since the .next() node , i hard coded the phase in which i wish to roll back to, however this is not ideal as it would be optimal for the user to be able to 'select' which phase they were to send it back...

Therefore , I have two questions : 
1. Is my method of the roll back correct? (maybe there is a better way to do the roll back instead of calling the process and hard code refreshing the fields)
2. Is there a way to select which part of the flow the user wish to roll back to?

Thanks and  i would greatly appreciate anybody's advise

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the good BPMN practice pattern is to finish flow as soon as possible, and do not involve complex cycles. That makes code simple, clean and easy to support. Simplifies reporting and keeps all revisions of data inside different process instances

With Viewflow flow-restart decision could be implemented as flow.View that records user decision and following flow.Handler that starts new flow instance using one of additional flow.StartFunction

[image: flow sample]

Another option, is to use flow.View to record user decision and flow.Switch to step into another task.

Generally, BPMN separates user tasks and gateways, that lead to all decisions been recorded, before used.

Comment: Hey there , i really appreciate you taking time off to reply my queries . About the first option , it would be recorded as an entirely new process is that correct? im afraid about users getting confused as its more intuitive to think of 1 process = 1 item and a centralised place (the process detail page) where they could see all the decisions made in the processing phase